# Reactjs - reset component state on props change best practice

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

What is the best practice to reset a component state when only a prop pointer changed, and not the values?

In this example, the parent component makes a map in this render, and all rerenders will provoke a `useEffect` of his child.

I know there are multiple solutions to this issue, but what is the best practice?

- use "fast-deep-equal" and check by values? If yes, why does react not include `this.` hooks?
- memorize with a callback? If yes, should the callback be in the parent, child or both?
- use an additional prop like `listId`?

```
const fullList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "item 1",
        disable: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "item 2",
        disable: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "item 3",
        disable: false
    }
];

function Child(props) {

    const {
        list
    } = props;

    const [colored, setColor] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setColor(undefined)
    }, [list]);

    return <div>
        <input type="button" value="Child (Set Color)" onClick={() => setColor(true)}/>
        <div style={{...colored && {color: 'red'}}}>
            {list.map(l => <div key={l.id}>
                           {l.text}
                        </div>)}
        </div>
    </div>;
}

function Parent () {
   const [triggerRender, fireRender] = React.useState(false); 
   const list = fullList.map(({id, text}) => ({id, text}));
  
   return (<div>
              <input type="button" value="Parent (Render)" onClick={()=> fireRender(r => !r)}/>
              <Child list={list}/>
            </div>);
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

thanks

Comment: So you want the `color` reset to happen only when the list actual values change, right? And do you want an approach that totally respects your component structure or are you willing to change it in order to achieve a nice solution?

Comment: yes, only when values change I want to reset my component state, no matter structure, here it's a simple case trying to understand what the better approach in react to reuse component, for example in this case imagine the parent have a filter that will affect the list data, in this case yes I want to reset the state, but not in all parent rerender

Comment: Could you specify which prop are you talking about? Is it the prop`list` of the `Child` component?

Comment: yes the prop list of the Child component change on each Parent component render